# Scala: How to invoke method with type parameter and manifest without knowing the type at compile time?

Tags: scala, reflection, types, implicit

I have a function with the following signature:

```
myFunc[T <: AnyRef](arg: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) = ???
```

How can I invoke this function if I do not know the exact type of the argument at the compile time?

For example:

```
val obj: AnyRef = new Foo()    // At compile time obj is defined as AnyRef,
val objClass = obj.getClass    // At runtime I can figure out that it is actually Foo
// Now I would need to call `myFunc[Foo](obj.asInstanceOf[Foo])`,
// but how would I do it without putting [Foo] in the square braces?
```

I would want to write something logically similar to:

```
myFunc[objClass](obj.asInstanceOf[objClass])
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

The question is invalid - As @DaoWen, @Jelmo and @itsbruce correctly pointed, the thing I was trying to do was a complete nonsense! I just overthought the problem severely.
THANK YOU guys! It's too bad I cannot accept all the answers as correct :)

So, the problem was caused by the following situation:

I am using [Salat](https://github.com/novus/salat) library to serialize the objects to/from BSON/JSON representation.
`Salat` has an `Grater[T]` class which is used for both serialization and deserialization.
The method call for **deserialization** from BSON looks this way:

```
val foo = grater[Foo].asObject(bson)
```

Here, the role of type parameter is clear. What I was trying to do then is to use the same Grater to **serialize** any entity from my domain model. So I wrote:

```
val json = grater[???].toCompactJSON(obj)
```

I immediately rushed for reflection and just didn't see an obvious solution lying on the surface. Which is:

```
grater[Entity].toCompactJSON(obj)  // where Entity...

@Salat trait Entity                // is a root of the domain model hierarchy
```

Sometimes things are much easier than we think they are! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong way to work with a type-safe OO language.  If you need to do this, your design is wrong.

```
myFunc[T <: AnyRef](arg: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) = ???
```

This is, of course, useless, as you have probably discovered.  What kind of meaningful function can you call on an object which might be *anything*?  You can't make any direct reference to its properties or methods.

> I would want to write something logically similar to:

```
myFunc[objClass](obj.asInstanceOf[objClass])
```

Why?  This kind of thing is generally only necessary for very specialised cases.  Are you writing a framework that will use dependency injection, for example?  If you're not doing some highly technical extension of Scala's capabilities, this should not be necessary.

I bet you know *something* more about the class, since you say you don't know the *exact* type.  One big part of the way class-based OO works is that if you want to do something to a general type of objects (including all its subtypes), you put that behaviour into a method belonging to the class.  Let subclasses override it if they need to.

Frankly, the way to do what you are attempting is to invoke the function in a context where you know enough about the type.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that while I was writing this answer the author of the question realized that he does not need to resolve `Manifest`s at runtime. However, in my opinion it is perfectly legal problem which I resolved successfully when I was writing Yaml [de]serialization library, so I'm leaving the answer here.

---

It is possible to do what you want using `ClassTag`s or even `TypeTag`s. I don't know about `Manifest`s because that API is deprecated and I haven't worked with it, but I believe that with manifests it will be easier since they weren't as sophisticated as new Scala reflection. FYI, `Manifest`'s successor is `TypeTag`.

Suppose you have the following functions:

```
def useClasstag[T: ClassTag](obj: T) = ...

def useTypetag[T: TypeTag](obj: T) = ...
```

and you need to call then with `obj: AnyRef` as an argument while providing either `ClassTag` or `TypeTag` for `obj.getClass` class as the implicit parameter.

`ClassTag` is the easiest one. You can create `ClassTag` directly from `Class[_]` instance:

```
useClasstag(obj)(ClassTag(obj.getClass))
```

That's all.

`TypeTag`s are harder. You need to use Scala reflection to obtain one from the object, and then you have to use some internals of Scala reflection.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.api
import api.{Universe, TypeCreator}

// Obtain runtime mirror for the class' classloader
val rm = runtimeMirror(obj.getClass.getClassLoader)

// Obtain instance mirror for obj
val im = rm.reflect(obj)

// Get obj's symbol object
val sym = im.symbol

// Get symbol's type signature - that's what you really want!
val tpe = sym.typeSignature

// Now the black magic begins: we create TypeTag manually
// First, make so-called type creator for the type we have just obtained
val tc = new TypeCreator {
  def apply[U <: Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]) =
    if (m eq rm) tpe.asInstanceOf[U # Type]
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Type tag defined in $rm cannot be migrated to other mirrors.")
}
// Next, create a TypeTag using runtime mirror and type creator
val tt = TypeTag[AnyRef](rm, tc)

// Call our method
useTypetag(obj)(tt)
```

As you can see, this machinery is rather complex. It means that you should use it only if you *really* need it, and, as others have said, the cases when you really need it are very rare.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't going to work. Think about it this way: *You're asking the compiler to create a class Manifest (at compile time!) for a class that isn't known until run time.*

However, I have the feeling you're approaching the problem the wrong way. Is `AnyRef` really the most you know about the type of `Foo` at compile time? If that's the case, how can you do anything useful with it? (You won't be able to call any methods on it except the few that are defined for `AnyRef`.)

Comment: It may be useful to do such thing. Consider the following example. You need to encode some kind of metainformation about some class (maybe for some kind of serialization). You make the API for writing this metainfo in type-safe manner. But then you need to write this metamodel for a big number of classes. Naturally, some kind of reflective/macro solution comes to mind. But your API for creating the metamodel is type-safe, probably using `TypeTag`s/`Manifest`s. So, you really need a way to call this type-safe API while you don't know anything about types statically.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev - In that case you'd need to do pattern matching or something inside the method, and the generic type parameter for the method is still useless. My point wasn't that you'd never use `AnyRef` as a supertype, but rather that this combination of `AnyRef` and the generic type doesn't make any sense.

Comment: generic parameters offer a convenient interface to the *programmer*. If it is carefully designed, it will improve type safety of your program. However, sometimes this interface should be called by other code, not by the programmer directly. For example, you have a method `construct[T: TypeTag]` and you need to call it with a type which can be obtained only in runtime, e.g. with type of a parameter of a case class. I'm not saying that this is a common use case, but nonetheless it does exist.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve and a little more context could be helpful. Anyway, here's my 2 cents.

Using Manifest will not help you here because the type parameter needs to be known at compile time. What I propose is something along these lines:

```
def myFunc[T](arg: AnyRef, klass: Class[T]) = {
  val obj: T = klass.cast(arg)
  //do something with obj... but what?
}
```

And you could call it like this:

```
myFunc(obj, Foo.class)
```

Note that I don't see how you can do something useful inside `myFunc`. At compile time, you cannot call any method on a object of type T beside the methods available for AnyRef. And if you want to use reflection to manipulate the argument of `myFunc`, then there is no need to cast it to a specific type.